# NullInjectorError: No provider for ChangeDetectorRef

Tags: angular

Using Angular 5, I am firing a function, `select()` from one component only for selection that triggers another function, `getqr()` in another component for printing. `getqr()` fires a web request for items that are selected from the first component. In order to update the print view to reflect the request, I am using `ChangeDetectorRef`. Doing this gives me an error of:

`StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[PrintComponent -> ChangeDetectorRef]: 
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[PrintComponent -> ChangeDetectorRef]: NullInjectorError: No provider for ChangeDetectorRef!`

I'm not sure what the issue is here as I cannot (and should not have to) add `ChangeDetectorRef` to `providers` in app.module.ts.

Here is the TS for the selection component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { PrintComponent } from './print/print.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  docs;

  constructor(public http: HttpClient, public print: PrintComponent) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get("https://portal.oldnational.com/corporate/portalsupport/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Document Separator Barcodes')/items?$top=1000&$orderBy=DocumentGroup,Title").subscribe(data => {
      this.docs = data['value'];
    });
  }

  select(ID, selected){
    if (selected == true) {
      this.print.selecteddocs.push(ID); //Adds selection to array on Print Component
    }
    else {
      var index = this.print.selecteddocs.indexOf(ID);
      this.print.selecteddocs.splice(index, 1); //Removes selection from array on Print Component
    }
    this.print.getqr(); //fires getqr() from Print Component
  }

}
```

Here is the TS for the print component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';
.....

@Component({
  selector: 'app-print',
  templateUrl: './print.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./print.component.css'],
})
export class PrintComponent implements OnInit {
  barcodeitems;
  selecteddocs = [];

  constructor(public http: HttpClient, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef){
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  getqr() {
    console.log("selecteddocs array", this.selecteddocs);
    let filterQuery = this.selecteddocs.map(i => `ID eq '${i}'`).join(" or ");
    let url = `https://portal.oldnational.com/corporate/portalsupport/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Document Separator Barcodes')/items?$top=1000&$orderBy=ID&$filter=${filterQuery}`
    this.http.get(url).subscribe(data => {
      console.log("data.value", data['value']); //Correctly logs results
      this.barcodeitems = data['value'];
      this.cdr.detectChanges(); //Attempt to refresh the view
    });
  }

}
```

What can I do to fix this issue or update the view of the Print Component after a selection is made?

Comment: Why is the print component injected into the app component? (not sure if injecting a component that way can cause the issue)

Comment: It was injected to use in functions like `this.print.getqr();`

Comment: Hi @cfoster5! I'm facing the same issue. In my case I solve it because i was using ChangeDetectorRef also in a service more than in app.component. Solved by removing its usage in the service, i've kept it just in the main app component. Have you managed to solve this issue?

Answer (score 11):

In my case i was calling `changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef` from a service.

it works fine. once `changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef`   moved from service to a component.

Do not import ChangeDetectorRef into services

Comment: Please explain why this is a solution. What does your solution do, how does it solve the problem.(It should also have an educational effect on people who find this question because they have a similar problem. )

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by passing the reference to ChangeDetector from the app component,

i.e. change the constructor in `app.component.ts` to

```
constructor(
    changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
    ms: MobileService) {
  ms.setChangeDetector(changeDetectorRef);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I run into such situation "NullInjectorError: No provider for ChangeDetectorRef" in Angular 17 application.
And it was "flickering" one. When a page was open by link from other page - nothing happens but there is error when the page open by direct link.

The reason was in injected TranslocoDatePipe which is not actually used.

[image]

the page was created in Angular 15 and working well.

There is other story with NullInjectorError. In that time it happened only on "ng build". "ng serve" worked well.
There was big refactoring included 2 components which become abstract for to be a base for inheriting.

and I spent whole day to found the reason - and it was "styleUrls: ['']".
[image]

So Angular 17 brought some surprises.